# Search Firefox Inspector by attribute value

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, web-inspector

In Firefox, when I open up the Inspector, I can search the HTML using the small box in the top-right corner and entering values like `a` to search all links, etc. And I can use `[href]` to search all elements with a `href` attribute.

But how can I search for all links with a `href` attribute that contains `test`, for instance? So that it matches `<a href="test">Test</a>`, as an example.

I tried `[href~=test]` and `[href~="test"]` but neither seem to work.

Comment: When using the contains word selector, words have to be separated by whitespace. That's why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `*=` instead of `~=`:

- `[title~="flower"]` Selects all elements with a title attribute containing the **word** "flower"
- `a[href*="w3schools"]` Selects every  element whose href attribute value contains the **substring** "w3schools"

[source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: There's a lot of bad info in w3schools. They seem to just be really good at SEO. Please use a more reputable source such as MDN.

Comment: I agree, but not everything is wrong in w3schools (like this copied part) :)

Comment: You are correct in this case, but it's a terrible resource in general and should be avoided at all costs. [Here is the MDN resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below selector. It worked for me when testing in Firefox

`a[href*="test"]`

**Edit** I cant read. The "contains word" selector (`~=`) must be used when there are words separated by whitespace. Since there is only one word, it wont work. The "contains" selector (`*=`) is what you're looking for. The original answer has also been updated